# can use form group with formbuilder for updating one field in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rest, formgroups

I have created an api to update one field, I have tested : this.appointmentForm.get('id_t').value to get the value of the input in the form HTML, but it doesn't work.
Any idea about this ?!!

component.html

```
     <form [formGroup]="appointmentForm" >     
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Id technicien</mat-label>
            <input formControlName="id_t" matInput/>
        </mat-form-field>
     </form>
     <div mat-dialog-action [align]="'end'">
         <button mat-raised-button color="warn" mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
         <button style="margin-left: 8px;" mat-raised-button color="primary" 
         (click)="updateAppointment()">Update</button>
     </div>
```

component.ts
updateAppointment(){

```
this.api.putAppointment(this.appointmentForm.get('id_t').value,this.editData.id)
.subscribe({
  next:(res)=>{
    alert("update Successfuly");                   
    this.appointmentForm.reset();
    this.dialogRef.close('update');  
  },
  error:()=>{
    alert("Error while updating the record");
  }                      
})
```

}

Comment: your question is not clear enough... did the alert open? also can't see where you update the form .. you should do something like `this.appointmentForm.get('id_t').setValue('new value')`

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question is why you can't access some value in created form? You need to provide whole code with your formbuilder and also see your console if there are any errors.

If you need example how to create form with formbuilder and access control value inside - here it can be helpful https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n9wavp